# how do I check at which line the value changes in a csv file?

Tags: php, html, csv, while-loop

I'm creating a table with telephone number of the a company those are separated in different organizations and in other departments. I have those informations saved in a CSV file.

My Question is how can i check when the department changes so that i can make a Spacing or that i can style it later on?

```
This is the Structure of my CSV file.

organization;name;phonenumber;department
```

PHP script:

```
function printPhonenumbers($org) {
  $handle = fopen ('csvPHP.csv','r');
  while (($csv_array = fgetcsv ($handle, 0, ';')) !== FALSE ) {
    for ($i=5; $i <= count($csv_array) ; $i=$i+1) {
      if ($csv_array[0] == $org) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$csv_array[1]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$csv_array[2]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: you need to somehow remember (save?) the previous values - so you know if the new ones are different.

Comment: @matiit Do you have any simple example for this, i've tried now multiple times but i don't know how i should "save" it in a smart way

Answer (score 1):

As @matiit pointed out, try and remember the last known value:

Example:

```
function printPhonenumbers($org) {
  $handle = fopen ('csvPHP.csv','r');
  $last_department = null;
  while (($csv_array = fgetcsv ($handle, 0, ';')) !== FALSE ) {
    for ($i=5; $i <= count($csv_array) ; $i=$i+1) {
      if ($last_department != $csv_array[3]) {
         // here the department is different from the previous one. Remember to 'save' the new value
         $last_department = $csv_array[3];
         // do your thing
      } else {
         // still the same department
         if ($csv_array[0] == $org) {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>".$csv_array[1]."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$csv_array[2]."</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
         }
      }
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```